# Wordpress - Search page for custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, search, custom-post-type

I started to use Wordpress for a project, and using the following plugin [Download Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/download-monitor/)

My page listings based on taxonomies all work fine, but im struggling with the search results

My form

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="right" id="download-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
            <div>
               <input type="text" value="" name="dlm_download" id="dlm_download" placeholder="Search" />
              </div>
        </form>
```

So when i search and get the results `mywebsite.com/?dlm_download=query`the home page gets show.

Than i created after research `search-dlm_download.php`, still get redirected to home.

Than i found this thread [How to create a custom search for custom post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89886/how-to-create-a-custom-search-for-custom-post-type) on wordpress exchange that does not work either.

So i am a bit stuck, could someone please point out what i am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
`search-dlm_download.php`

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <div id="page" class="border-top clearfix">

    <div id="subtitle">

        <h1><?php _e("Search Results for '$s'", 'framework') ?></h1>

        <div id="breadcrumb"><?php the_breadcrumb(); ?></div>

        <div class="hr4"><span class="seperator"></span><span class="lightborder"></span></div>

    </div>

    <div id="content-part">

            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="search-entry post-entry">   

                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                <div class="meta">
                    <?php _e('Posted on', 'framework'); ?> <strong><?php the_time('d.m.Y'); ?></strong> · <?php _e('Posted in', 'framework'); ?> <?php the_category(', ') ?>
                </div>

                <div class="entry">
                    <?php wpe_excerpt('wpe_excerptlength_blog', 'wpe_excerptmore'); ?>
                </div>

                <div class="entry-footer"></div>

            </div>



            <?php endwhile; ?>


            <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/framework/functions/nav.php' ); ?>

    </div>

    <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar-right">
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div>

    </div>

    <?php else : ?>

    <div id="page" class="border-top clearfix">

            <div id="subtitle">

                <h1><?php _e('No Results Found', 'framework') ?></h1>

                <div id="breadcrumb"><?php the_breadcrumb(); ?></div>

                <div class="hr4"><span class="seperator"></span><span class="lightborder"></span></div>

            </div>

            <div class="wrap clearfix">

            <div id="content-part">

                    <div class="no-search-result">
                        <p><?php _e("Sorry, no results found. Try different words to describe what you are looking for.", 'framework') ?></p>
                    </div>

            </div>

            <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar-right">
                <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
            </div>

    </div>

    </div>

    <?php endif; ?>



<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Your action in your search form points to your homepage. Try having an empty action

Comment: that was the first thing i tried, same result

Comment: i do not really think the action causing the problem

Comment: Can you paste your search script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found a solution by breaking the default search to 2 parts

If anybody needs it in the future you can find it here [Create multiple search templates for custom post types](http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/template/create-multiple-search-templates-for-custom-post-types/)